# SQL for displaying and sorting messages and their replies in one table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, messaging

I have written a simple messaging system for a CMS I am developing and am having a hard time finding the best way to grab all the messages and their replies ordered by the newest (message or reply).

I have a table called "*messages*" that has the fields:
*id, active[1,0], subject, message, datetime, user_from, user_to, reply_id*

It's all straight forward and the *reply_id* is empty for main level messages and contains the parent *id* for replies. I am at a loss for how to write the SQL to grab all the main level messages in *datetime DESC* order based on themselves AND their replies. I'm sure it's done with a UNION of some sort but my SQL skills are lacking. And if the same SELECT can give a count of the replies within each main level message that would be amazing!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's late and I'm tired but I think you could try something like that:

```
SELECT main.*, COUNT(reply.id) AS cnt_replies, MAX(reply.datetime) AS max_datetime
FROM posts AS main
LEFT JOIN posts AS reply
    ON main.id = reply.reply_id
GROUP BY main.id
HAVING main.reply_id IS NULL
ORDER BY max_datetime DESC
```

**EDIT:** fixed query
**EDIT2:** now includes messages without any replies

Comment: Thanks you so much, this seems like it would be perfect... one question though: What is the **main.id** referring to? I get this error:

`Unknown column 'main.id' in 'where clause`

Comment: @cbh Sorry my mistake, I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if that works better. Cheers!

Comment: @Sly Actually, this query doesn't include messages that **don't** have replies... hmm

Comment: @cbh You're right! Check out my answer, I just edited the query. Replace `IS NULL` by `= 0` depending on what you use.

Comment: @Sly Nailed it! Thanks again... I've been staring at [link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for hours trying to grasp joins!

Comment: @Sly - Another issue... main messages that don't have replies are not sorted by date (since their "max_datetime" field is empty), I tried

Comment: @Sly Does this fix it logically? `ORDER BY datetime DESC, max_datetime DESC`